# sorting array of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting

HI i have a following array of dictionaries and and i want to sort the array using the the key "BirthDate" and my code is as follows

```
NSLog(@"nodeEventArray == %@", temp);
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"BirthDate"
                                    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedEventArray = [temp
                             sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"sortedEventArray == %@", sortedEventArray);
```

but I was unable to sort properly can any one please tell me how to sort the array of dictionary based on "BirthDate" key .Since birth date is coming as string from service

sample array of dictionaries:

```
   nodeEventArray = (
        {
        BirthDate = "05/04/1986";
        Email = "";
        FirstName = Test;
        IsSpouse = 0;
        LastName = Test;
        MiddleInitial = "";
        PatientID = "";
        Phone = "";
        ScacntronCSVId = 40409;
        SlotID = 1;
        UserName = "Tes_02192013010055";
    },
        {
        BirthDate = "02/14/1986";
        Email = "";
        FirstName = Guest;
        IsSpouse = 0;
        LastName = Guest;
        MiddleInitial = "";
        PatientID = "";
        Phone = "";
        ScacntronCSVId = 40410;
        SlotID = 2;
        UserName = "Gue_02192013014725";
    },
        {
        BirthDate = "02/17/1987";
        Email = "";
        FirstName = User;
        IsSpouse = 0;
        LastName = User;
        MiddleInitial = "";
        PatientID = "";
        Phone = "";
        ScacntronCSVId = 40411;
        SlotID = 3;
        UserName = "Use_02192013020726";
    }
    )
```

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for: [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Comment: When you say "sort properly" what do you mean? The "BirthDate" is only a string and so it will sort in ascending alphabetical order.

Comment: Yeah, why aren't you holding *BirthDate* using an `NSDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using sortDescriptor you can use comparator

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [nodeEventArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormator = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSDate *date1 = [dateFormator dateFromString:[[obj1 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[[obj1 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"] lastPathComponent] withString:@"2013"]];
        NSDate *date2 = [dateFormator dateFromString:[[obj1 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[[obj1 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"] lastPathComponent] withString:@"2013"]];
        if ([date1 earlierDate:date2] == date1) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }else{
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

    }];
```

Comment: working fine but need ascending and descending sorting as well but its working for ascending only not for descending and need to sort with month and date also not only with year.

Comment: I have modified my logic according to your requirement. Also if you swap the NSOrderedAscending and NSOrderedDescending then your sorting will be reversed

Comment: thanks for you update ,i got it and for ascending and descending i am using as mentioned below  if (dobSorted == YES) {
            
            //For Ascending Order
            return [[df dateFromString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"]] compare:[df dateFromString:[dict2 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"]]];
            
        }else{
            
            //For Desending Order
            return -1 *[[df dateFromString:[dict1 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"]] compare:[df dateFromString:[dict2 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"]]];
            
        }

Answer (score 1):

I assume the array was coming from a server or something (hence the "Username" bit) but still, it would be better to store each user/event/whatever in an object with an NSDate. That way you can just sort by the date and it works.

However, if you want to sort this array then...

If you want to sort by BirthDate (using the date) then you'll need to convert the strings into actual NSDates.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

[blah sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:[obj1 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"];
    NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[obj2 objectForKey:@"BirthDate"];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

This should do it.

It will convert the strings into dates and then compare them.

Comment: He's using the stupid american format `MM/dd/yy`, not the excellent UK format `dd/MM/yy` :D

Comment: Although I would encourage him to use `NSDate` to store the date anyway, rather than convert to it temporarily, for the obvious benefits that brings.

Comment: True, I assumed the array was coming from a server or something (hence the "Username" bit) but still, it would be better to store each user in an object with an NSDate.